# Optimizing the Vba code

Tags: vba, excel, parsing, href, innertext

There is a program ,that parsing website . Program works well , but too long . I want to simplify/speed it up. Tell me please ,maybe there are any specialized sites on this issue ? For any help I will be grateful .

How program works:

1. First , by the hyperlink , the program goes to the site , where it finds a certain table of elements
2. Then it takes out the “href” of each element , turns it into a hyperlink , and inserts it into Excel in the 1-st table
3. Then it extracts the text of each element and inserts it into Excel in the 2-nd table
4. Then it goes through the elements of the 1-st and 2-nd tables , so that in the 3-rd table each element contains a “hyperlink +text”

   ```
    Sub Softгиперссылки()
     Application.DisplayAlerts = False


     Call mainмассивы

     Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   End Sub


   Sub mainмассивы()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String
    Dim iLoop As Long
    Dim book1 As Workbook
    Dim sheetNames(1 To 19) As String
    Dim Ssilka As String


    sheetNames(1) = "Лист1"
    sheetNames(2) = "Лист2"
    sheetNames(3) = "Лист3"
    sheetNames(4) = "Лист4"
    sheetNames(5) = "Лист5"
    sheetNames(6) = "Лист6"
    sheetNames(7) = "Лист7"
    sheetNames(8) = "Лист8"
    sheetNames(9) = "Лист9"
    sheetNames(10) = "Лист10"
    sheetNames(11) = "Лист11"
    sheetNames(12) = "Лист12"
    sheetNames(13) = "Лист13"
    sheetNames(14) = "Лист14"
    sheetNames(15) = "Лист15"
    sheetNames(16) = "Лист16"
    sheetNames(17) = "Лист17"
    sheetNames(18) = "Лист18"
    sheetNames(19) = "Лист19"

    'пропускаем ошибку

     Set book1 = Workbooks.Open("E:\Super M\Проект ставки\Поиск решения\Усов 7\Условия для андердогов\6.xlsm")

     iLoop = -1

    With book1.Worksheets("Лист1").Range("R34:R99")

    For Each r In .Rows
        If r.Value = 1 Then

           iLoop = iLoop + 1
           Ssilka = r.Offset(, -13).Hyperlinks.Item(1).Address
           .Parent.Parent.Worksheets(sheetNames(1)).Activate
           .Parent.Parent.Save
           extractTable Ssilka, book1, iLoop

         End If
     Next r

    End With
    book1.Save
    book1.Close
    Exit Sub


   End Sub


     Function extractTable(Ssilka As String, book1 As Workbook, iLoop As Long)
     Dim oDom As Object, oTable As Object, oRow As Object
     Dim iRows As Integer, iCols As Integer
     Dim x As Integer, y As Integer
     Dim data()
     Dim oHttp As Object
     Dim oRegEx As Object
     Dim sResponse As String
     Dim oRange As Range
     Dim Perem1 As String
     Dim Perem2 As String



    'для гиперссылки

    ' get page
     Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
     oHttp.Open "GET", Ssilka, False
     oHttp.Send

    ' cleanup response
     sResponse = StrConv(oHttp.responseBody, vbUnicode)
     Set oHttp = Nothing

    sResponse = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))

    Set oRegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
   With oRegEx
   .MultiLine = True
   .Global = True
   .IgnoreCase = False
   .Pattern = "<(script|SCRIPT)[\w\W]+?</\1>"
   sResponse = .Replace(sResponse, "")
   End With
   Set oRegEx = Nothing

    ' create Document from response
     Set oDom = CreateObject("htmlFile")
     oDom.Write sResponse
     DoEvents

     ' table with results, indexes starts with zero
   Set oTable = oDom.getelementsbytagname("table")(3)

   DoEvents

   iRows = oTable.Rows.Length
   iCols = oTable.Rows(1).Cells.Length

   ' first row and first column contain no intresting data
   ReDim data(1 To iRows - 1, 1 To iCols - 1)

   ' fill in data array
   For x = 1 To iRows - 1
   Set oRow = oTable.Rows(x)

   For y = 1 To iCols - 1
        If oRow.Cells(y).Children.Length > 0 Then
           data(x, y) = oRow.Cells(y).getelementsbytagname("a")(0).getattribute("href")

       End If

   Next y
    Next x

    Set oRow = Nothing
    Set oTable = Nothing
    Set oDom = Nothing

     ' put data array on worksheet

    Set oRange = book1.ActiveSheet.Cells(110, 26 + (iLoop * 21)).Resize(iRows - 1, iCols - 1)
    oRange.NumberFormat = "@"
    oRange.Value = data
    oRange.Replace What:="about:", Replacement:="http://allscores.ru/soccer/"
    Set oRange = Nothing

     '!!!! для текста

    ' get page
    Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    oHttp.Open "GET", Ssilka, False
    oHttp.Send

   ' cleanup response
   sResponse = StrConv(oHttp.responseBody, vbUnicode)
   Set oHttp = Nothing

   sResponse = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))

   Set oRegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
   With oRegEx
   .MultiLine = True
   .Global = True
   .IgnoreCase = False
   .Pattern = "<(script|SCRIPT)[\w\W]+?</\1>"
   sResponse = .Replace(sResponse, "")
   End With
   Set oRegEx = Nothing

      ' create Document from response
      Set oDom = CreateObject("htmlFile")
      oDom.Write sResponse
       DoEvents

      ' table with results, indexes starts with zero
      Set oTable = oDom.getelementsbytagname("table")(3)

      DoEvents

      iRows = oTable.Rows.Length
      iCols = oTable.Rows(1).Cells.Length

     ' first row and first column contain no intresting data
      ReDim data(1 To iRows - 1, 1 To iCols - 1)

      ' fill in data array
      For x = 1 To iRows - 1
      Set oRow = oTable.Rows(x)

     For y = 1 To iCols - 1
        If oRow.Cells(y).Children.Length > 0 Then
           data(x, y) = oRow.Cells(y).innerText

       End If

   Next y
   Next x

   Set oRow = Nothing
   Set oTable = Nothing
   Set oDom = Nothing

    ' put data array on worksheet

   Set oRange = book1.ActiveSheet.Cells(185, 26 + (iLoop * 21)).Resize(iRows - 1, iCols - 1)
    oRange.NumberFormat = "@"
    oRange.Value = data

     Set oRange = Nothing

     '!!!!! цикл для текст+гиперссылка


   For A = 0 To 4
   For B = 0 To 65

    Perem1 = book1.ActiveSheet.Cells(110 + B, (26 + (iLoop * 21)) + A).Value
    Perem2 = book1.ActiveSheet.Cells(185 + B, (26 + (iLoop * 21)) + A).Value

     book1.ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(34 + B, (26 + (iLoop * 21)) + A), Address:=Perem1, TextToDisplay:=Perem2
    Next
    Next



   End Function
   ```

Comment: If you have working code which merely needs improvements then you're probably in the wrong place with this post. [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is where they handle existing / working code and do their upmost to improve it in terms of speed, security, sustainability, and longevity including best-practices. Give it a try. They're good!

Comment: @Ralph ,Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

There are number of things that could be done to improve efficiency, but that is probably better conducted on CodeReview.

I will make mention, however, of your use of late-bound variables. You'll achieve much faster performance with early-binding:

```
'Late-bound variable declaration and creation
Dim oRegExp As Object
Set oRegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With oRegEx
   '....
End With

'Late-bound reference only:
'No variable declaration required, the variable only survives as long as the With Block
With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    '....
End With

'Early-bound - Add a reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
'This is the fastest and most efficient use of a new RegExp object, and you get intellisense in the VBE
With New RegExp
    '....
End With
```

You should also consider installing the free, open-source Rubberduck VBA add-in for the Visual Basic Editor (disclaimer - I'm a contributor), which will come with many more suggestions and optimizations for you, and it will automatically indent your code for improved readability.